# Are transferFrom and transferTo transfer all bytes if invoked with FileChannel?

Tags: java, nio, filechannel

Some internet documents show me examples look like,

```java
FileChannel target;
FileChannel source;
target.trasferFrom(source, 0, source.size()); // done!
```

or

```java
FileChannel source;
FileChannel target;
source.transferTo(0, source.size(), target); // done!
```

But document says that these methods can actually transfers less than given.

Are `transferFrom` and `transferTo`, **if `source` or `target` is an instance of `FileChannel`**, transfer for all given count?

Shouldn't I have to loop like this?

```java
for (long count = Files.size(source); count > 0L;) {
    final long transferred = readable.transferTo(
        readable.position(), count, writable);
    readable.position(readable.position() + transferred);
    count -= transferred;
}

for (long count = Files.size(source); count > 0L;) {
    final long transferred = writable.transferFrom(
        readable, writable.position(), count);
    writable.position(writable.position() + transferred);
    count -= transferred;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the documentation is correct, you have to loop.

Comment: I haven't used channels much and I would loop much like with an InputStream, but the Javadoc is explicit about the possible reasons for not transferring all requested bytes: "Fewer than the requested number of bytes are transferred if this channel's file contains fewer than count bytes starting at the given position, or if the target channel is non-blocking and it has fewer than count bytes free in its output buffer." So it seems possible to do without a loop if the target has enough free bytes or is blocking. If that list is not exhaustive than the Javadoc is not clear about this point.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt In the case of `transferFrom()` the source isn't necessarily a file, a case the Javadoc is unclear about.